# Spring JPA Hibernate H2

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Receiving a javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException for embeddable entity when trying to use Spring Data Repository to save data. Seems like the select statement is not finding data for my embedded entity `CommunicationPreference`. How can I fix this error?

Stack Trace:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to find com.talentreef.notification.recipient.persistent.models.CommunicationPreference with id 61390ce8-719c-44e4-9cab-57070d728456; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.talentreef.notification.recipient.persistent.models.CommunicationPreference with id 61390ce8-719c-44e4-9cab-57070d728456

    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:378)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:144)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$ExposeRepositoryInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:364)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy106.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.talentreef.notification.recipient.persistent.services.RecipientPersistService.upsert(RecipientPersistService.java:33)
    at com.talentreef.notification.recipient.persistent.services.RecipientPersistentServiceTest.shouldSaveRecipient(RecipientPersistentServiceTest.java:127)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.talentreef.notification.recipient.persistent.models.CommunicationPreference with id 61390ce8-719c-44e4-9cab-57070d728456
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$JpaEntityNotFoundDelegate.handleEntityNotFound(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1288)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1160)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:682)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:464)
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.resolve(ManyToOneType.java:239)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:457)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.replace(EntityType.java:358)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.replace(AbstractType.java:164)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.replace(TypeHelper.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.copyValues(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:502)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:257)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:334)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:927)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:897)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$6.cascade(CascadingActions.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:490)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:415)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:523)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:455)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:418)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:459)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:334)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:905)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:891)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:309)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy104.merge(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:538)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:359)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:644)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:608)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    ... 43 more
```

Hibernate Queries:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        recipient0_.recipient_id as recipien1_1_1_,
        recipient0_.alias as alias2_1_1_,
        recipient0_.email as email3_1_1_,
        recipient0_.firstname as firstnam4_1_1_,
        recipient0_.lastname as lastname5_1_1_,
        recipient0_.mobile as mobile6_1_1_,
        audiences1_.recipient_recipient_id as recipien1_3_3_,
        audience2_.audience_id as audience2_3_3_,
        audience2_.audience_id as audience1_2_0_,
        audience2_.alias as alias2_2_0_,
        audience2_.client_id as client_i3_2_0_,
        audience2_.recipient_id as recipien4_2_0_,
        audience2_.type as type5_2_0_ 
    from
        notification.recipient recipient0_ 
    left outer join
        notification.recipient_audiences audiences1_ 
            on recipient0_.recipient_id=audiences1_.recipient_recipient_id 
    left outer join
        notification.recipient_audience audience2_ 
            on audiences1_.audiences_audience_id=audience2_.audience_id 
    where
        recipient0_.recipient_id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        audience0_.audience_id as audience1_2_1_,
        audience0_.alias as alias2_2_1_,
        audience0_.client_id as client_i3_2_1_,
        audience0_.recipient_id as recipien4_2_1_,
        audience0_.type as type5_2_1_,
        followers1_.audience_id as audience2_4_3_,
        followers1_.follower_id as follower1_4_3_,
        followers1_.follower_id as follower1_4_0_,
        followers1_.audience_id as audience2_4_0_,
        followers1_.client_id as client_i3_4_0_,
        followers1_.follower_recipient as follower4_4_0_,
        followers1_.recipient_id as recipien5_4_0_ 
    from
        notification.recipient_audience audience0_ 
    left outer join
        notification.recipient_follower followers1_ 
            on audience0_.audience_id=followers1_.audience_id 
    where
        audience0_.audience_id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        follower0_.follower_id as follower1_4_0_,
        follower0_.audience_id as audience2_4_0_,
        follower0_.client_id as client_i3_4_0_,
        follower0_.follower_recipient as follower4_4_0_,
        follower0_.recipient_id as recipien5_4_0_ 
    from
        notification.recipient_follower follower0_ 
    where
        follower0_.follower_id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        recipientp0_.preference_id as preferen1_7_0_,
        recipientp0_.client_id as client_i2_7_0_,
        recipientp0_.list_id as list_id6_7_0_,
        recipientp0_.last_modified as last_mod3_7_0_,
        recipientp0_.recipient_id as recipien4_7_0_,
        recipientp0_.source_type as source_t5_7_0_ 
    from
        notification.recipient_preference recipientp0_ 
    where
        recipientp0_.preference_id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        communicat0_.list_id as list_id1_0_0_,
        communicat0_.email as email2_0_0_,
        communicat0_.sms as sms3_0_0_,
        communicat0_.stream as stream4_0_0_ 
    from
        notification.preference_list communicat0_ 
    where
        communicat0_.list_id=?
```

Data Model:

```
@Builder
@Getter
@Entity
@Embeddable
@Table(name = RecipientPreferenceTable.NAME, schema = Notification.SCHEMA_NAME)
public class RecipientPreference {

  @Id
  @Column(name = RecipientPreferenceTable.COLUMN_PREFERENCE_ID, unique = true, length = 16)
  private UUID id;

  @Column(name = RecipientPreferenceTable.COLUMN_RECIPIENT_ID, nullable = false, length = 16)
  private UUID recipientId;

  @Column(name = RecipientPreferenceTable.COLUMN_CLIENT_ID, nullable = false)
  private String clientId;

  @OneToOne
  @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = CommunicationPreferenceTable.COLUMN_LIST_ID, nullable = false))
  @JoinColumn(name = CommunicationPreferenceTable.COLUMN_LIST_ID)
  private CommunicationPreference communicationPreference;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  @Column(name = RecipientPreferenceTable.COLUMN_SOURCE_TYPE)
  private SourceType sourceType;

  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  @Column(name = RecipientPreferenceTable.COLUMN_LAST_MODIFIED)
  private Date lastModified;

  protected RecipientPreference() {}

  public RecipientPreference(UUID id,
                             UUID recipientId,
                             String clientId,
                             CommunicationPreference communicationPreference,
                             SourceType sourceType,
                             Date lastModified) {

    this.id = id;
    this.recipientId = recipientId;
    this.clientId = clientId;
    this.communicationPreference = communicationPreference;
    this.sourceType = sourceType;
    this.lastModified = lastModified;
  }
}

@Builder
@Getter
@Entity
@Embeddable
@Table(name = CommunicationPreferenceTable.NAME, schema = Notification.SCHEMA_NAME)
public class CommunicationPreference {

  @Id
  @Column(name = CommunicationPreferenceTable.COLUMN_LIST_ID, length = 16)
  private UUID id;
  private boolean sms;
  private boolean email;
  private boolean stream;

  protected CommunicationPreference(){}

  public CommunicationPreference(UUID id, boolean sms, boolean email, boolean stream) {
    this.id = id;
    this.sms = sms;
    this.email = email;
    this.stream = stream;
  }
}
```

Data Populated when saved:
[image]

Comment: I am not sure I follow you. This is an in-memory database running during a unit-test

Comment: Exception message is quite clear on the problem - there's no `CommunicationPreference with id 61390ce8-719c-44e4-9cab-57070d728456` present in the database. You should either create it before the test or modify `RecipientPreference`'s relation to `CommunicationPreference`:  `@OneToOne(        cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)`. [A beginner’s guide to JPA and Hibernate Cascade Types](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/)

Comment: Thanks, @MartinBG you are quite right the exception message is very clear. The Cascading worked. I guessed I just figured it would do by default for inserts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `CommunicationPreference with id 61390ce8-719c-44e4-9cab-57070d728456` present in the database.

It should be either created before the test or `RecipientPreference`'s OneToOne relation to `CommunicationPreference` should be modified to allow its automatic creation:

```
public class RecipientPreference {

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = CommunicationPreferenceTable.COLUMN_LIST_ID, nullable = false))
  @JoinColumn(name = CommunicationPreferenceTable.COLUMN_LIST_ID)
  private CommunicationPreference communicationPreference;

}
```

[A beginner’s guide to JPA and Hibernate Cascade Types](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/)